# tex4ebook, biblatex and footnotes/endnotes with correct output, but errormessage

Tags: biblatex, endnotes, tex4ebook

I used the following MWE in the `Testdocument.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\else
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\fi
\makeindex[intoc=false,columns=1,noautomatic,title=Alphabetisches Verzeichnis]
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[hyperindex=true,
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfkeywords={Philosophy}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\begin{document}

    "`Ein zitierter Satz eines Autors."'\footcite{AG1986}
    
    \nocite{AG1987}

\clearpage
\theendnotes

\clearpage
\defbibnote{BibVorwort}{Erläuterung zum Literaturverzeichnis.}
\defbibheading{TestBib}{%
    \chapter*{\scshape #1}\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \ifdefined\HCode\else\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur}\fi}
\printbibliography[title=Literatur,prenote=BibVorwort,heading=TestBib]

\end{document}
```

It gives a correct output in the epub file, only if I ignore the following error message:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex)                Footnote detection will not work.


! Package biblatex Error: Patching 'endnotes' package failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...

l.41 \begin{document}
```

I would like to know how I can fix the error with getting the same correct output. Does anybody know what to do?

Update 1:

The `sample.tex` file looks minimized like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[hyperindex=true,
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfkeywords={Philosophy}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

    "`Ein zitierter Satz eines Autors."'\footcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage
\theendnotes

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The `myconfig.cfg` file is as follows:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{DocumentLanguage}{de}
\EndPreamble
```

As a result there is still the above error message, but the epub file seems correct with hyperlinks made.

Update 2:
This is the further reduced code for Testdocument.tex (which corresponds to the `Testdocument.log` file on `gist.github.com`, see below)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\begin{document}

    "`Ein zitierter Satz eines Autors."'\footcite{sigfridsson}

\theendnotes

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I replace your `.bib` file, which I don't have, with a file I have (`\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`) and choose citation key from that file (`sigfridsson`) instead of `AG1986`, I can compile your example without error. Which version of `biblatex` and `tex4ebook` are you running?

Comment: Also is all of the code needed to reproduced the problem? Can you minimise your code example further? Ideally you would make the example as small as possible. For such a fully minimal example it would also be interesting to see the full `.log` file. It might be too long to be added in the question, but you can upload it to text-sharing websites such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/, https://gitlab.com/explore/snippets, ...

Comment: I should mention I compiled the example file with pdfLaTeX. If another compiler should be run, please mention that in the question as well.

Comment: I use `tex4ebook v0.3i` and biblatex.sty from `texlive 2022`. I use also pdfLaTeX. In addition I tried your `biblatex-examples.bib` and citation key `sigfridsson`. The pdf is as before correct. But I still got the same error message as in the question. I reduced the config file to a minimum, but the error leaves unchanged. Biblatex seems to complain about footnote and endote.

Comment: I don't get any error from your sample too. Can you update your question with the minimum files, both TeX and BibTeX?

Comment: I can compile the new code without a problem as well. I even generated the `myconfig.cfg`, though I cannot see which bit of the code loads it. I still think the code might be a bit too verbose. Do you need to load all the font packages for things to go wrong? Do you need the `\clearpage`s? Do you need `hyperref`? Can you fully minimise the code and then share the `.log` file with us (as suggested above)?

Comment: I reduced the code further but the error message above remains. I will show the `Testdocument.log` file in `https://gist.github.com/', hope this will help to find the key. Thank you.

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/Thomkrates/2955740ee72568e5164820c1c9e5860a

Comment: How exactly do you call LaTeX on your document? The `.log` file suggests that quite a lot of code is passed to TeX together with the file name. My `.log` file has `**./filename.tex` where yours has `**\makeatletter...\input \detokenize{Test
document.tex}`

Comment: I use TeXstudio as editor with integrated functions for pdflatex and other. The code for pdflatex is `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. I think I didn't do here anything, this must be filled out via installation.

Comment: from your log file, I can see that your TeX distro is quite old. the error you experience is similar to one that I fixed last year, but configuration files for TeX4ht on your system don't contain this fix.

Comment: Thank you Michal for this info and your fixes. I use texlive 2022. Obviously I need to get the newest versions from, but which files do I need to update?

Comment: I see that Texlive 2023 will tomorrow be released: `"Plan for TeX Live 2023: ... 19mar: public release (also of MacTeX)."`. This might really be solving the problem here addressed, hopefully. I will try it the next days and eventually come back with other questions. Thank you to you both `moewe` and `michal.h21` for your patience and help.

Comment: You can also update your TeX Live using  the `tlmgr update --all` command

Comment: Oh, that seems interesting. How exactly does this work? - Just to go in the command line in the root directory and then run this command? With open internet connection? - If I do this I got the following message: `TeX Live 2022 is frozen
and will no longer be routinely updated.  This happens when a new
release is made, or will be made shortly. ...` with some further information.

Comment: You executed the command correctly. It is useful to execute it once in a while, to get a new version of installed packages. If you didn't get an update because TeX Live is frozen, then it will be best to wait for TeX Live 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments the answer is hidden. Here in short:

I waited some days for the newest version of TeX Live 2023, installed it, and tried it again. It solved the addressed problem.